# How can I install subversion 1.5.1 (very old release)

Tags: software-installation, svn

I need to install subversion 1.5.1 somewhere temporarily (e.g in a virtual machine) in order to convert an old BDB based SVN repository to FSFS.

Things I've tried so far:

1. Doing `apt-get install subversion` on an Ubuntu 12.04 VM installed subversion 1.6.XX which was not good for my old repo due to:

   ```
   $ svnadmin verify .
   svnadmin: Berkeley DB error for filesystem 'db' while opening environment:

   svnadmin: DB_VERSION_MISMATCH: Database environment version mismatch
   svnadmin: bdb: Program version 4.8 doesn't match environment version 4.6
   ```
2. Doing `apt-get install subversion` on an Ubuntu 10.04 VM, in hope that it would install subversion 1.5.XX, didn't work due to apt errors.
3. Attempt to find a debian/ubuntu specific `.deb` package for version 1.5.1, but couldn't find any.
4. Attempt to build from source using this (maybe naive?) method:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gcc
   sudo apt-get install zip

   cd /tmp
   wget http://download.oracle.com/berkeley-db/db-4.6.21.zip
   unzip db-4.6.21.zip
   cd /tmp/db-4.6.21/build_unix
   ../dist/configure
   make

   cd /tmp
   wget https://www.openssl.org/source/old/0.9.x/openssl-0.9.8j.tar.gz
   tar -xvf openssl-0.9.8j.tar.gz
   cd /tmp/openssl-0.9.8j
   ./config no-asm
   make

   sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev

   cd /tmp
   wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/subversion/subversion-1.5.1.tar.gz
   tar -xvf subversion-1.5.1.tar.gz
   wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/subversion/subversion-deps-1.5.1.tar.gz
   tar -xvf subversion-deps-1.5.1.tar.gz
   cd /tmp/subversion-1.5.1
   ./configure --without-apache --without-neon --without-swig --with-berkeley-db=/tmp/db-4.6.21/build_unix --with-ssl=/tmp/openssl-0.9.8j
   make
   ```

But still after many trial and error I cannot get subversion to `./configure` due to:

```
configure: error: Berkeley DB not found.
```

Is there anything else I should try to get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Ubuntu we [can get Subversion 1.5.4](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/subversion/), you already know this.

But according to the contents of http://archive.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/subversion/ we have Debian release with subversion `1.5.1dfsg1-7`. These files are dated as `2011-12-26 01:55`. So according to dates (checked on [distrowatch](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=debian)) - you need Debian 5.0 (lenny).

You can create [schroot](https://wiki.debian.org/Schroot) for it in any supported Ubuntu version:

```
sudo apt-get install schroot debootstrap -y

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/schroot/chroot.d/lenny.conf
[lenny]
description=Debian 5 lenny
directory=/srv/chroot/lenny
root-users=$USER
type=directory
users=$USER
EOF

sudo mkdir -p /srv/chroot/lenny

sudo debootstrap lenny /srv/chroot/lenny http://archive.debian.org/debian
```

update package lists in the schroot environment (ignore KEYEXPIRED messages by pressing <kbd>y</kbd>):

```
schroot -c lenny -u root apt-get update
```

and then check `subversion`-related packages:

```
schroot -c lenny apt-cache policy subversion
```

> ```
> subversion:
>   Installed: (none)
>   Candidate: 1.5.1dfsg1-7
>   Version table:
>      1.5.1dfsg1-7 0
>         500 http://archive.debian.org lenny/main Packages
> ```

and finally install them

```
schroot -c lenny -u root apt-get install subversion
```

If you need to chroot to the Debian 5.0 (lenny) environment just run `schroot -c lenny -u root`.

Let's do it together.

1. Enter chroot with `schroot -c lenny -u root`
2. Run command `svn --version` in the chroot and get:

   > ```
   > # svn --version            
   > svn, version 1.5.1 (r32289)
   > compiled May 31 2011, 16:16:34
   > ...
   > ```
3. For sure run command `dpkg -l | egrep -i "svn|subversion"` in the chroot and get:

   > ```
   > # dpkg -l | egrep -i "svn|subversion"
   > ii  libsvn1                         1.5.1dfsg1-7             Shared libraries used by Subversion
   > ii  subversion                      1.5.1dfsg1-7             Advanced version control system
   > ```

I recorded [Asciinema cast](https://asciinema.org/a/ZEROttQHli7xNwQ90U2nfjJHs) to show how it works.

Seems to be working solution. Long live Debian!

Comment: Thanks for this radical solution. First of all, the first link you mentioned contains svn related modules for other systems and not svn itself. Now, to the schroot solution, I'm getting an error on `schroot -c lenny -u root apt-get update`. It gives me `W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org lenny Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1520281423 KEYEXPIRED 1337087218`. This consistently happens both in vanilla (vagrant) installations of `Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS` and `Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS`.

Comment: But I see that if I continue with the rest of the commands I end up having subversion installed. Although it is `(Debian sbuild) 1.6.10 (04 May 2014)`.

Comment: I was in hurry while writing this answer, but for me it really ends with svn 1.5.1. I recorded [asciinema cast](https://asciinema.org/a/ZEROttQHli7xNwQ90U2nfjJHs) for you.

Comment: Great. I'm very happy that it worked. I'll use such method to run old software from Debian (and Ubuntu). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, I don't think you'll be able to easily find a distro that still works nowadays and ships with that old of a subversion... So I think building from source is probably the way to go.

I think the problem you're running into while building from source is that you're trying to use the dependencies from their build directories rather than install directories. So while the linker will probably be able to find the compiled libraries from there, it's possible the compiler will have trouble finding the include files it needs...

My recommendation is that you install the dependencies to the system (under `/usr/local`, which should be the default), then try to build subversion pointing to them.

In short, for db and openssl:

```
sudo make install
```

For Subversion:

```
./configure --without-apache --without-neon --without-swig \
    --with-berkeley-db=/usr/local --with-ssl=/usr/local
```

If your dependencies don't install to `/usr/local` by default, try passing `--prefix=/usr/local` or similar to their configure scripts.

I didn't try this myself, so the details might be a little bit off... But hopefully this is enough to unblock you. (Please post a comment indicating whether this worked or not!)

If you still have errors such as `configure: error: Berkeley DB not found.`, take a look inside `config.log` which should show you what `./configure` was trying to do when it failed. Scroll to the end, then scroll up the lines including output, you might be able to see which files it was trying to find or which C program it was trying to build. Post more details here (or post your whole `config.log` to a pastebin) and we might be able to further help you here. Good luck!